# WordPress add_rewrite_rule works locally but not on server

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, wordpress-theming

I'm able to get `add_rewrite_rule` to work locally with MAMP, but not on my DreamHost production server.

I'm attempting to prettify the URLs for individual pets at http://www.pawsnewengland.com/our-dogs-list/. The ugly URLs follow this structure: our-dogs-list/?view=pet-details&id=12345, and a custom function uses `$_GET` variables to process in the information.

In my `functions.php` file, I've included this:

```
function rewrite_pet_url() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        "our-dogs-list/pet-details/([0-9]+)/?$",
        "index.php/our-dogs-list/?view=pet-details&id=$1",
        "top"
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_pet_url');
```

I've also tried this with the same results:

```
function rewrite_pet_url() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        "our-dogs-list/pet-details/([0-9]+)/?$",
        "index.php/our-dogs-list/?view=pet-details&id=$matches[1]",
        "top"
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_pet_url');
```

And in an effort to simply test that rewrites would work at all, tried this:

```
function rewrite_pet_url() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        "fake",
        "index.php/about",
        "top"
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_pet_url');
```

I'm flushing rewrite rules prior to testing, and have confirmed that the rewrite rules were added to the `.htaccess` file. For some reason, though, I'm seeing either a 404 page or a white screen and "No input file specified."

I'm able to get this working locally, so I have no idea what's breaking on a live server. Any insights?

### Update 1

I've gotten the rewrite "working" in the sense that it no longer causes any errors. Unfortunately, it now causes an unwanted redirect to the root URL.

```
function rewrite_pet_url() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%view%','([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%id%','([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'our-dogs-list/pet-details/([0-9]+)?$',
        'index.php/?page_id=1663&view=pet-details&id=$1',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_pet_url' );
```

With this, I can access the `view` and `id` variables using `get_query_var()`. However, instead of honoring `example.com/our-dogs-list/pet-details/12345`, WordPress redirects the page to `example.com/our-dogs-list/`.

Any idea what could be causing that? It's effectively making the rewrite rule useless.

Comment: You should activate debug on your production server to see what going on.

Comment: Hi Alex, doesn't that run the danger of displaying weird PHP error codes to the numerous people that visit this site each day?

Comment: @chris-fernandini You may use the Theme Test Drive plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-test-drive/. It allows you to let your users use a theme on your live site while you're using another one exclusively.

Comment: in your code (update 1) you use `index.php/?page_id=1663&view=pet-details&id=$1` i think you should write this without the slash `index.php?page_id=1663&view=pet-details&id=$1`

Comment: @BassJobsen - Just gave that a shot. Still seeing the same behavior. Thanks though.

Comment: For this URL, server responds- moved permanently: http://www.pawsnewengland.com/our-dogs-list/pet-details/12345

Any other rewrite rules interfering?

Answer (score 6):

This was to long to add as a comment.

I would add this to functions.php. I've changed your permalink a bit, my [demo plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20477363/1434155) explains what each function does:

```
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'pet_rewrite_url');
add_filter('query_vars', 'pet_query_vars'));
add_filter('admin_init',  'pet_flush_rewrite_rules');
add_action("parse_request", "pet_parse_request");


function pet_rewrite_url( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $new_rules = array(
         'our-dogs-list/pet-details/([0-9]+)/?$' => sprintf("index.php?pet-details=%s",$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1))
    );

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite->rules;
}

function pet_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'pet-details';
    return $query_vars;
}

function pet_flush_rewrite_rules() {
    $rules = $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->wp_rewrite_rules();
    if ( ! isset( $rules['our-dogs-list/pet-details/([0-9]+)/?$'] ) ) { // must be the same rule as in pet_rewrite_url($wp_rewrite)
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
}

function pet_parse_request($wp_query) {
    if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['pet-details'])) { // same as the first custom variable in pet_query_vars( $query_vars )
        // add your code here, code below is for this demo
        printf("<pre>%s</pre>",print_r($wp_query->query_vars,true));
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've written a guide on how to add custom permalinks, here's the example plugin (also [available at my site](http://soderlind.no/wordpress-plugins-and-permalinks-how-to-use-pretty-links-in-your-plugin/)):

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My Permalink Demo
Plugin URI: http://soderlind.no/archives/2012/11/01/wordpress-plugins-and-permalinks-how-to-use-pretty-links-in-your-plugin/
Description: Demo plugin to show how to implement your custom permalink for your plugin. To test, add the [mypermalink] or [mypermalink val="ipsum"] shortcode to a page or post.
Version: 1.0.1
Author: Per Soderlind
Author URI: http://soderlind.no/
*/

if (!class_exists('my_permalink')) {
    class my_permalink {

        function __construct(){
            // demo shortcode
            add_shortcode('mypermalink', array(&$this,'my_permalink_demo_shortcode'));

            // permalink hooks:
            add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', array(&$this,'my_permalink_rewrite_rule'));
            add_filter('query_vars', array(&$this,'my_permalink_query_vars'));
            add_filter('admin_init', array(&$this, 'my_permalink_flush_rewrite_rules'));
            add_action("parse_request", array(&$this,"my_permalink_parse_request"));
        }

        /**************************************************************************
         * Demo shortcode
         * A simple shortcode used to demonstrate the plugin.
         *
         * @see http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API
         * @param array $atts shortcode parameters
         * @return string URL to demonstrate custom permalink
         **************************************************************************/
        function my_permalink_demo_shortcode($atts) {
            extract(shortcode_atts(array(
                // default values
                'val'       =>   'lorem'
            ), $atts));
            return sprintf('<a href="%s">My permalink</a>',$this->my_permalink_url($val));
        }

        /**************************************************************************
         * Create your URL
         * If the blog has a permalink structure, a permalink is returned. Otherwise
         * a standard URL with param=val.
         *
         * @param sting $val Parameter to custom url
         * @return string URL
         **************************************************************************/
        function my_permalink_url($val) {
            if ( get_option('permalink_structure')) { // check if the blog has a permalink structure
                return sprintf("%s/my-permalink/%s",home_url(),$val);
            } else {
                return sprintf("%s/index.php?my_permalink_variable_01=%s",home_url(),$val);
            }
        }

        /**************************************************************************
         * Add your rewrite rule.
         * The rewrite rules array is an associative array with permalink URLs as regular
         * expressions (regex) keys, and the corresponding non-permalink-style URLs as values
         * For the rule to take effect, For the rule to take effect, flush the rewrite cache,
         * either by re-saving permalinks in Settings->Permalinks, or running the
         * my_permalink_flush_rewrite_rules() method below.
         *
         * @see http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries#Permalinks_for_Custom_Archives
         * @param object $wp_rewrite
         * @return array New permalink structure
         **************************************************************************/
        function my_permalink_rewrite_rule( $wp_rewrite ) {
            $new_rules = array(
                 'my-permalink/(.*)$' => sprintf("index.php?my_permalink_variable_01=%s",$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1))
                 /*
                 // a more complex permalink:
                 'my-permalink/([^/]+)/([^.]+).html$' => sprintf("index.php?my_permalink_variable_01=%s&my_permalink_variable_02=%s",$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),$wp_rewrite->preg_index(2))
                 */
            );

            $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
            return $wp_rewrite->rules;
        }

        /**************************************************************************
         * Add your custom query variables.
         * To make sure that our parameter value(s) gets saved,when WordPress parse the URL,
         * we have to add our variable(s) to the list of query variables WordPress
         * understands (query_vars filter)
         *
         * @see http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries
         * @param array $query_vars
         * @return array $query_vars with custom query variables
         **************************************************************************/
        function my_permalink_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
            $query_vars[] = 'my_permalink_variable_01';
            /*
            // need more variables?:
            $query_vars[] = 'my_permalink_variable_02';
            $query_vars[] = 'my_permalink_variable_03';
            */
            return $query_vars;
        }

        /**************************************************************************
         * Parses a URL into a query specification
         * This is where you should add your code.
         *
         * @see http://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview
         * @param array $atts shortcode parameters
         * @return string URL to demonstrate custom permalink
         **************************************************************************/
        function my_permalink_parse_request($wp_query) {
            if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['my_permalink_variable_01'])) { // same as the first custom variable in my_permalink_query_vars( $query_vars )
                // add your code here, code below is for this demo
                printf("<pre>%s</pre>",print_r($wp_query->query_vars,true));
                exit(0);
            }
        }

        /**************************************************************************
         * Flushes the permalink structure.
         * flush_rules is an extremely costly function in terms of performance, and
         * should only be run when changing the rule.
         *
         * @see http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules
         **************************************************************************/
        function my_permalink_flush_rewrite_rules() {
            $rules = $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->wp_rewrite_rules();
            if ( ! isset( $rules['my-permalink/(.*)$'] ) ) { // must be the same rule as in my_permalink_rewrite_rule($wp_rewrite)
                global $wp_rewrite;
                $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
            }
        }
    } //End Class
} //End if class exists statement

if (class_exists('my_permalink')) {
    $my_permalink_var = new my_permalink();
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. How might I apply this towards the specific problem I'm trying to address?

Comment: With permalinks switched off, is the following working?:

`index.php/our-dogs-list/?view=pet-details&id=1`

assuming `id=1` is a valid id

Comment: I have to few points to comment above. If you look at [the example at the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite#Examples) you'll see that you have to query the vars, othervise WordPerfect doesn't understad the new permalink you added .. and, you must use the correct filters and actions, not `init`

Comment: As noted above, I am using `get_query_vars`, which is the correct way to get `$_GET` variables. I have tested and that piece is working correctly. Both [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag) and this [tutorial from TutsPlus](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/the-rewrite-api-the-basics/) indicate that rewrite rules should be called at init or earlier. Your way works too, but mine isn't incorrect. Your code also caused the redirect, which shouldn't be happening.

Answer (score 2):

Your replacements look incorrect, try:

```
function rewrite_pet_url() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        "our-dogs-list/pet-details/([0-9]+)/?$",
        "index.php?view=pet-details&id=$1",
        "top"
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_pet_url');
```

Note the use of `index.php` and not `index.php/our-dogs-list/` as the destination.

Or maybe it's like this:

```
function rewrite_pet_url() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        "our-dogs-list/pet-details/([0-9]+)/?$",
        "our-dogs-list/index.php?view=pet-details&id=$1",
        "top"
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_pet_url');
```

Comment: Hi Dean, thanks, but I actually do want /our-dogs-list/ in the final URL. As I write this, though, I'm wondering if I should be using the page ID instead? So for example: `index.php?p=123&view=pet-details&id=$1`?

Comment: Edited the answer to include alternative

Comment: Remember that if you get the ugly URL's working first you will have an easier time.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try and report back. What's driving me nuts is that I can get this working just fine locally. Appreciate your help here!

Answer (score 2):

edit in your .htaccess

`RewriteRule ^our-dogs-list/pet-details/([0-9]+)?$ /index.php?page_id=1663&view=pet-details&id=$1 [L]` add this for `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` so you .hatcces would something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^our-dogs-list/pet-details/([0-9]+)?$ /wordpress/index.php?page_id=2&view=pet-details&id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**update**

from: http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

> IMPORTANT: By default, WordPress will not recognize custom querystring
>   variables used for rewrites. You must register your querystring
>   variables with WordPress. Simply use add_rewrite_tag() to do this, or
>   the above rewrite will not work! More information about capturing
>   querystring variable values after a rewrite can be found here.

so far i understand you should use: add_rewrite_tag() for `view` and `id` in your first example.

Comment: Per my post above, I am in fact using `add_rewrite_tag`, as well as `get_query_var` in my functions to get those variables. Additionally, `add_rewrite_rule` is already adding that snippet to my `.htaccess` file.

Comment: could you add your .htaccess to your question?